# FormView not saving data in Django

Tags: django, modelform, formview

I am trying to allow users to save details of a workout for a specific exercise through submitting a form. My ExerciseDetailView displays the form how I'd like it to:

```
class ExerciseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Exercise
    template_name = 'workouts/types.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExerciseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = WorkoutModelForm
        return context
```

But my problem is with saving the inputted data in the database. I have tried making both a FormView and a CreateView but am clearly missing something:

```
class ExerciseFormView(FormView):
    form_class = WorkoutModelForm
    success_url = 'workouts:exercise_detail'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ExerciseFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Here is my referenced WorkoutModelForm:

```
class WorkoutModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ['weight', 'reps']
```

My template:

```
<form action="{% url 'workouts:workout' exercise.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Urls:

```
path('exercise/<int:pk>/detail/', ExerciseDetailView.as_view(), name='exercise_detail'),
path('exercise/<int:pk>/detail/', ExerciseFormView.as_view(), name='workout'),
```

And for context here is my Workout model which contains a get_absolute_url method:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0)
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('exercise_detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

I am not receiving any errors, but when I submit the form my url remains the same, as I hoped, however the page just appears blank and the objects are not recorded. Can anybody please help me see what the problem is?

Comment: THe urls are perfectly overlapping, so it will always take the first view (the `ExerciseDetailView`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your view, the Django logic will never trigger this view, the URLs are perfectly overlapping, so that means that for a URL, it will always trigger the first view (here the `ExerciseDetailView`), you should make the paths non-overlapping, for example with:

```
path('exercise/<int:pk>/detail/', ExerciseDetailView.as_view(), name='exercise_detail'),
path('exercise/<int:pk>/workout/', ExerciseFormView.as_view(), name='workout'),
```

Triggering the logic will however not be sufficient, since it will not link the `Workout` to the necessary exercise, you can alter the logic to:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class ExerciseFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = WorkoutModelForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.exercise_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('workouts:exercise_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, although on submit I am now receiving an Integrity Error at /exercise/1/workout `NOT NULL constraint failed: workouts_workout.exercise_id`

Comment: @sgt_pepper85: sorry, I made a typo: it is `form.instance.exercise_id = ...`.

Comment: Genius. It is working perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Need use [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview)

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class ExerciseFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = WorkoutModelForm

...
```